# Is it possible to control Spotify on Apple TV 4K using Siri?

Tags: appletv, siri, spotify

I have an Apple TV 4K, and have installed the Spotify app. This works well to browse and play music on Spotify when using the remote.

Is it possible to find and play music on the Spotify app using Siri? The goal is to leave the TV off when playing music through my connected amplifier.

I'm finding that Siri doesn't seem to search the Spotify catalog. If I say "play X", Siri finds movies and TV shows matching "X".

Is there a keyword to use with Siri for Spotify, or is Spotify search not supported?

Comment: https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/27/20886783/spotify-siri-integration-support-ios-13-beta-launch-airpods

Comment: @ankii I saw that article but to my understanding it's saying two different things. (1) You can *control* Spotify with Siri on an iPhone running iOS 13 and (2) you can *install* Spotify on Apple TV. I don't believe it means you can control Spotify on Apple TV using Siri

Comment: have you tried the phrase which mentions Spotify ?